# How do I determine if my R installation on OS X has the "--enable-R-shlib" option enabled?

Tags: ruby, r, installation, rubygems

I've installed R on my OS X machine via the .pkg method. I'm trying to get a Ruby gem called RSRuby to work and though it installed correctly, it's throwing an error when I try to invoke the gem.

```
Fatal error: R home directory is not defined
```

The RSRuby documentation states that R should be installed with the option --enable-R-shlib. But the R documentation states that the Mac OS X installation does this by default. How can you verify that this option is enabled on an installation if you don't know it was explicitly called during installation?

I'm chasing down why RSRuby can't find R home directory and this seems like the most likely problem.

Per RSRuby documentation, I copied this into my home directory

```
[~]$ R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resource
```

And from the R console, this is the output:

```
> R.home()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

And during gem install, I ran this command:

```
gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=$R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
```

Also, these are the contents of my /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries folder:

```
[Libraries]$ ls
i386                    libRblas.dylib.dSYM     libgfortran.2.dylib
libR.dylib              libRblas.vecLib.dylib   libreadline.5.2.dylib
libR.dylib.dSYM         libRlapack.dylib        libreadline.dylib
libRblas.0.dylib        libRlapack.dylib.dSYM   ppc
libRblas.dylib          libgcc_s.1.dylib        x86_64
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Briefly:

1. You can check for `--enable-R-shlib` by looking at thethe binary of the resulting R built; on Linux I can do `ldd /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` which reveals that `libR.so` --- the shared R library --- is loaded by this binary. That is what other projects embedding R (RInside, littler, the R-in-Apache modules, ...) use and presumably what RSRuby would use.
2. If you get an error 'R home directory not defined' I would start by defining the environment variable `R_HOME`.

*Edit:* Regaring Question 1, on OS X, your dynamic libraries end in `.dylib`. So the directory listing you show clearly demonstrates that R was built with `--enable-R-shlib` as a compile-time option.  Regarding Question 2, the very first Google hit I got for `rsruby os x` clearly describes how to set `R_HOME` on OS X (as I had told you), see https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby.

Comment: I clarified my process in the original question (should have done that originally)

Comment: I believe I've found the OS X version of /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R. I posted it above in the question and it looks like I'm missing libR.so .... could this be the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Now that I know I have --enable-R-shlib I can search elsewhere for a solution. I have read the github explanation by the gem author and made reference to it in my question as RSRuby documentation. The first step in that installation is to ensure --enable-R-shlib was enabled during install, and I wasn't clear about it before you answered it for me. I already have the R_HOME variable defined (as evidenced in the R.home() info above). I'll have to  now proceed with other solutions suggested in the README. Thanks again.

Comment: Solution discovered. I thought I was setting the R_HOME variable from command line and I'm now under the impression that is not how it works. I put the line 'export R_HOME="my/R/home" in my .bash_profile and I'm no longer getting 'Fatal error: R home directory is not defined'. I'll have to read up on why it works this way and what export means, but for now I'm happy to get it working.

Comment: For reference, the OS X equivalent of `ldd` is `otool -L`